# Valid LINQ query, but invalid generating SQL

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5

Use Entity Framework 5, MS SQL Server CE. 
The LINQ query (valid, select product with options, values of options and count of products with relevant values of options):

```
var q = _db
    .Products
    .Where(p => p.ProductID == productName)
    .Select(p => new {
       p.ProductID,
       p.Title,
       Options = p
        .Options
        .Select(o => new {
            o.OptionId, 
            o.Title,
            Values = o
                .Values
                .Select(v => new {
                    v.OptionValueId,
                    v.Title,
                    v.OptionId,
                    CountProducts = _db.Products.Count(pp => pp.Options.Any(oo => oo.Values.Any(ooo => ooo.Title == v.Title)))
                })
        })
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Generation SQL (non-valid, [ Token line number = 31,Token line offset = 139,Token in error = SELECT ]):

```
SELECT 
[Project6].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
[Project6].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Project6].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Project6].[OptionId] AS [OptionId], 
[Project6].[Title1] AS [Title1], 
[Project6].[C1] AS [C2], 
[Project6].[OptionValueId] AS [OptionValueId], 
[Project6].[Title2] AS [Title2], 
[Project6].[OptionId1] AS [OptionId1], 
[Project6].[C3] AS [C3]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project5].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
    [Project5].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Project5].[OptionId] AS [OptionId], 
    [Project5].[Title1] AS [Title1], 
    [Project5].[OptionValueId] AS [OptionValueId], 
    [Project5].[Title2] AS [Title2], 
    [Project5].[OptionId1] AS [OptionId1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Project5].[OptionId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Project5].[OptionValueId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Project5].[OptionId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2], 
    [Project5].[C1] AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
        [Project1].[Title] AS [Title], 
        [Project1].[OptionId] AS [OptionId], 
        [Project1].[Title1] AS [Title1], 
        [Project1].[OptionValueId] AS [OptionValueId], 
        [Project1].[Title2] AS [Title2], 
        [Project1].[OptionId1] AS [OptionId1], 
        CASE WHEN ([Project1].[OptionId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Project1].[OptionValueId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [Products] AS [Extent4]
            WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
                1 AS [C1]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Extent5].[OptionId] AS [OptionId]
                    FROM [Options] AS [Extent5]
                    WHERE [Extent4].[ProductID] = [Extent5].[Product_ProductID]
                )  AS [Project2]
                WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
                    1 AS [C1]
                    FROM [OptionValues] AS [Extent6]
                    WHERE ([Project2].[OptionId] = [Extent6].[OptionId]) AND ([Extent6].[Title] = [Project1].[Title2])
                )
            )) END AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
            [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
            [Join1].[OptionId1] AS [OptionId], 
            [Join1].[Title1] AS [Title1], 
            [Join1].[OptionValueId] AS [OptionValueId], 
            [Join1].[Title2] AS [Title2], 
            [Join1].[OptionId2] AS [OptionId1]
            FROM  [Products] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[OptionId] AS [OptionId1], [Extent2].[Title] AS [Title1], [Extent2].[Product_ProductID] AS [Product_ProductID], [Extent3].[OptionValueId] AS [OptionValueId], [Extent3].[Title] AS [Title2], [Extent3].[OptionId] AS [OptionId2]
                FROM  [Options] AS [Extent2]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [OptionValues] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[OptionId] = [Extent3].[OptionId] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[ProductID] = [Join1].[Product_ProductID]
            WHERE [Extent1].[ProductID] = @p__linq__0
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project5]
)  AS [Project6]
ORDER BY [Project6].[ProductID] ASC, [Project6].[C2] ASC, [Project6].[OptionId] ASC, [Project6].[C1] ASC
```

EF could generate incorrect code.

Comment: There's nothing syntactically wrong with that SQL (though it may return the wrong detail)

Comment: Error [ Token line number = 31,Token line offset = 139,Token in error = SELECT ]

Comment: I am saying that if you run the query you posted, it will not give you an error.

Comment: Just to show what I mean, here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d944e/1/0)

Comment: Thanks! The problem in MS SQL CE. EF incorrectly generates code for it.

Comment: Looks like you're gonna have to restructure the query until it's OK. The part `CountProducts = ...` seems to be the culprit.

Comment: MS SQL CE do not approved "SELECT" in "CASE ... WHEN ... ELSE" construction. :(